# Boost C++ libraries for gcc-arm toolchain

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, arm

I have no trouble building 1.35.0, as well as 1.36.0 on the timesys arm-gcc toolchain, both statically (link-static) as well as dynamically (.so, default option).

However, when I try to link a simple sample filesystem app:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char* fileName = argv[1];
    std::cout << "file: " << fileName << " => " << fs::exists(fileName) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following linker error:

```
developer@eldp01:~/boost/test$ /opt/timesys/at91sam9263_ek/toolchain/bin/armv5l-timesys-linux-gnueabi-gcc 
  exists.cpp -o exists.exe -I ../boost_1_35_0/ -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lstdc++ -L .

/tmp/ccex3NGb.o: In function `boost::detail::atomic_decrement(int*)':
exists.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6detail16atomic_decrementEPi[boost::detail::atomic_decrement(int*)]+0x1c): 
  undefined reference to `__sync_fetch_and_add_4'

/tmp/ccex3NGb.o: In function `boost::detail::atomic_increment(int*)':
exists.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6detail16atomic_incrementEPi[boost::detail::atomic_increment(int*)]+0x1c): 
  undefined reference to `__sync_fetch_and_add_4'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Does anyone know how I can get Boost to build for the gcc-arm toolchain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add in file 'boost_1_35_0/boost/config/user.hpp':

```
#define BOOST_SP_USE_PTHREADS
```

btw, you need to set the gcc tool-chain in file 'boost_1_35_0/tools/build/v2/user-config.jam' to:

> ```
> using gcc
>         : arm
>         : /opt/timesys/at91sam9263_ek/toolchain/bin/armv5l-timesys-linux-gnueabi-gcc
> ;
> ```

This will solve the problem of linking now.

Answer (score 3):

An almost identical question was answered [here](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2008/04/135597.php) on the Boost mailing list.