# How to build Boost Libraries for Code Warrior IDE (v5.7) for RVDS 3.0?

Tags: boost

I am using Boost.Regex library to write a code for 10 digit mobile no. verification.I have compiled the Boost library using bjam.exe for msvc.
Now I want to run the same code for a BREW handset.For generating the executable (mod file) for the handset, I compile the C++ code using RVDS 3.0.The IDE used is Code Warrior 5.7

Can any body please tell me the way to compile boost library for RVDS 3.0.I am using armcc compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to rebuild the boost libraries with the appropriate compiler set to `--toolset` parameter of bjam. Here is the bjam reference: [Boost Jam](http://www.boost.org/doc/tools/jam/index.html)

Comment: Could you please tell me which toolset shoulld I use if Iwant to use armcc compiler on Windows OS.

Comment: see if this question gives you any hints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241581/boost-c-libraries-for-gcc-arm-toolchain